# Can I use the Spring Security @PreAuthorize on my own annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations

Can i use `@PreAuthorize` on annotations?

In Spring i can use annotations like `Component` and `DependsOn` in annotations, like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Component
@DependsOn(CoreInitializerConfig.ROLE_INITIALIZER_ID)
public @interface WebComponent
{

}
```

and it works well. But when i try to use `PreAuthorize` the same way:

```
@Target(
{
    ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD
})
@Component
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_READ_SETTINGS')")
public @interface SettingsAuthorized
{

}
```

Isnt working, i tried it in a MVC Controller pojo and in a Bean's method and didn't work, i had to put it explicitly:

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_READ_SETTINGS')") 
public class SettingsController
{
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problema by adding `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`
Its also recommended to add `@Documented` and `@Inherited` to the final annotation, so it resulted:

```
@Target(
{
    ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD
})
@Component
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_READ_SETTINGS')") 
public @interface SettingsAuthorized
{

}
```